# String append with Null Check Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

What would be ideomic way to append String with NULL check? Perhaps this is stupid question, but I am curious to know the best way.

**I tried these-**

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val foo: String? = null
    val bar = "bar"

    println("__println(\"\$foo \$bar\")")
    println("$foo $bar")

    println("__println((if (foo != null) \"\$foo \" else \"\") + (if (bar != null) \"\$bar \" else \"\"))")
    println((if (foo != null) "$foo " else "") + (if (bar != null) "$bar " else ""))

    println("__println((\"\$foo \" ?: \"\") + (\"\$bar \" ?: \"\"))")
    println(("$foo " ?: "") + ("$bar " ?: ""))

    println("__println((foo ?: \"\") + (bar ?: \"\"))")
    println((foo ?: "") + (bar ?: ""))

    println("__println(foo + \" \" + bar)")
    println(foo + " " + bar)

    var string = ""
    if (foo != null) string += "$foo, "
    if (bar != null) string += "$bar"
    println("__println(string)")
    println(string)
}
```

**Output**

> ```
> __println("$foo $bar")
> null bar
> __println((if (foo != null) "$foo " else "") + (if (bar != null) "$bar " else ""))
> bar 
> __println(("$foo " ?: "") + ("$bar " ?: ""))
> null bar 
> __println((foo ?: "") + (bar ?: ""))
> bar
> __println(foo + " " + bar)
> null bar
> __println(string)
> bar
> ```

**Purpose**

I have Location Data Class, in that I have address_line_1, city, state, country etc.

I want get full address string with appending all fields with null check. Please note I want append an space and comma also when value is not Null.

Comment: Counterquestions: what do you want to append instead? and what is your preference? If I need a default value, I go with `foo ?: "<default>"`. If `null` printed is ok, I just keep it as is, i.e. `"$foo"`. Your `"$foo " ?: ""`-variants are invalid or at least they do not make sense. `"<anything>"` will never be `null` (also `""` will never be `null`).. Your first and last variant seem equal to me. I would go for the first in this particular case. So summarizing: I would go for `"$bar ${foo ?: "<default>"}"` or just ` "$bar $foo"` and sometimes even with `if/else/when` if it makes sense.

Comment: Note also: as your `bar` is of type `String` it will never be `null` and as such, you do not need to take care of a possible `null` value, i.e. `bar != null` is always `true`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Counterquestions: what do you want to append instead? and what is your preference?

If I need a default value, I go with `foo ?: "<default>"`.

If it is ok if `null` is printed, I just keep it as is, i.e. `"$foo $bar"`.

If instead you just wanted to concatenate a list of strings which may or may not contain `null` values, you may also be interested in something like the following:

```
listOfNotNull(foo, bar).joinToString(" ")
```

Now regarding your update of the question... Assuming something like the following as data class:

```
data class Location(val line1 : String?, val line2 : String?, val line3part1 : String?, val line3part2 : String?)
```

A possible usage of [`listOfNotNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/list-of-not-null.html) assuming that empty lines should not be printed could like:

```
with(yourLocation) {
        // the outer listOfNotNull contains the lines:
        listOfNotNull(
            line1,
            line2,
            // inner ListOfNotNulls are specific concatenations, which may lead to an empty line (that's why takeIf is also here)
            listOfNotNull(line3part1, line3part2).takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() }
                ?.joinToString(" ")
            ).joinToString("\n")
    }.run(::println)
}
```

If you would require something like `"($nullable)"` I would go for:

```
nullable?.let { "($it)" }
```

which then again can be used within the `listOfNotNull`.

Comment: I have updated question with purpose, please let me know the good solution.

Comment: In above example `listOfNotNull(foo, bar).joinToString(", ")` prints nothing.

Comment: Yes, it just concatenates a `String`, which you then can assign to a variable or print immediately (e.g. by adding `.run(::println)` at then end).

Comment: no problem... just updated the answer to reflect a possible variant using `listOfNotNull` with an address class...

Comment: I just wanted to add that you need to be careful with the last case: `nullable?.let { "($it)" }` because it still results in the string "null" when being appended of course. 
E.g. `"a" + nullable?.let { "($it)" }` results in "anull".
If your desired result is "a", you need to write
`"a" + (nullable?.let { "($it)" } ?: "")`

Comment: correct, if you don't use `listOfNotNull`... if you use `listOfNotNull` it is filtered out again... so basically I rather meant something like: `listOfNotNull(..., nullable?.let { "($it)" }).joinToString("\n")`

Comment: Awesome idea with the `listOfNotNull` @Roland

Comment: @BenjaminBisinger thanks, but why are the parentheses are needed? I thought the lambda was skipped when target null ...

Comment: @apsommer `nullable?.let { "($it)" }` is an expression that is evaluated to `null`. Without the parentheses, you get `"a" + null ?: ""`. In that case `"a" + null` is executed first which results in "anull" and only then this expression is checked with the elvis operator. 
If you don't want to have `null` printed you must never have `string + null`. This is solved with the parenthesis, `(nullable?.let { "($it)" } ?: "")` is evaluated to "", so you have `"a" + ""` instead of `"a" + null`.
Or in other words: Although the lambda function is skipped, the expression still evaluates to `null`.

Comment: @BenjaminBisinger awesome, thanks. That one was eating at me.

Answer (score 1):

use this logic

```
var foo: String? = null
var bar = "bar"

foo?.let { foo += bar }?: run { foo="" }
println(foo)  // null not print

foo?.let { bar.let { foo += bar } }
println(foo)   //output is  bar
```

Comment: In this value of `foo` is changing, which is not a good way to concat.

Comment: Can you please tell mean of `run`?

Comment: if  variable value is null means it goes run part..its like if else statement...here ?. is null checker

Comment: Please check my purpose in updated question. Let me know if this would be best way?